# Square gradient background image, corner radius and transparency

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I find it hard to describe the effect I want with words so I created it in Photoshop and you can see the image below:

[image: in PS]

As you can see I have a red square with a 38pixel border. The border is outside and its style is set to shape burst. But unfortunately I don't think a similar style is in CSS. The border color is then set to linear gradient with the color inside being the same red as the square and the outer color is set to transparent white. Don't pay attention to the green that is the underneath layer just to show the transparency of the border.

What I would like to know, is if there is ANY way to get to achieve this effect with CSS or jQueryUI maybe.

I have been trying for a while in [THIS JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/151xhxdr/1/), but I don't know how to make it more like a square.

Here's the code in use in the fiddle above

```
<div class="test"></div>


    .test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(closest-side, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0, rgba(255,0,0,1) 75%, rgba(244,90,90,0.5) 88%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(closest-side, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0, rgba(255,0,0,1) 75%, rgba(244,90,90,0.5) 88%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-image: radial-gradient(closest-side, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0, rgba(255,0,0,1) 75%, rgba(244,90,90,0.5) 88%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    background-clip: border-box;
    -webkit-background-size: auto auto;
    background-size: auto auto;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

How about the below, using an `inset` box shadow:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 20px green;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 40px 20px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Or...for for an outset border without the green:

```css
div {
  background: red;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 20px #FF0303;
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px 20px #FF0303;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: you beat me to it! +1

Comment: First time for everything- I'm usually lagging behind you!

Comment: Oh wow it was that easy?! Thank you guys! I've googled and went through like 8 pages and each had really complicated code. Thank you.

Comment: I just realized something. Since you make the "transparent color by forcing the actual color I am not really able to use an image as background that would be visible through it then am I? Say I'd want this url('http://i.imgur.com/rid7udW.jpg'); as my background for the body I am not able to see it through the "white" or "green" transparency...Although I  guess I can just use drop shadow for that maybe?

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane - Not sure I follow. The blur is transparent, it isnt another colour being mixed in.

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/151xhxdr/2/ instead of green I'd like the background. But not by typing in yellow but actually making in transparent.

Comment: @CreamWhippedAirplane:
Then why not using the second option (outset border) as proposed: http://jsfiddle.net/151xhxdr/3/ ?

Comment: Maybe Cream is referring to transparent inset box shadow. Then, the backgroundcolor takes precedence what is not desired. Didnt find a solution to this