# Blending box colors in CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]I'm making a website for fun, and I want an effect where 4 boxes are layered and blend into each other but I don't know how to blend them.

```css
.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #333333;
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 45px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 1750px;
  height: 870px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1a1a1a, #333333);
}

.box3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 150px;
  top: 125px;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 700px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #333333, #4d4d4d);
}

.box4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #666666;
  border-radius: 15px;
  left: 250px;
  top: 250px;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 450px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #4d4d4d, #666666);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried using a linear gradient but it didn't really work, I also tried looking for something but couldn't really find anything on Youtube. I except a frontpage where you can see each box but they blend.

Comment: hi, when you say you want them to blend, could you clarify what you mean? a screenshot or image of what you want might help as well

Comment: Don't use `px` width in this responsive era. Use responsive units.

Comment: Instead of hex codes, you might be looking for `rgba` or `hsla` colors, which can be partially (or fully!) transparent to elements 'behind' them.

Comment: I have added a new picture to show what I'm looking for but I see that it could look like a gradient but I want it to be so it is like a gradient between the borders of the colors but still be visible difference between them.

Comment: But I mean if I could get it to look layered and like their some space between them would also be really nice.

Comment: `mix-blend-mode` is your friend: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question and comments (if I've understood it wrong, you're welcome to clarify it further and I'll happily update), I believe you're asking for boxes layered on top of each other with a sort of "gradient" or blurred edges between them (so no sharp edges).

I can see three main solutions, each with pros and cons:

1. You can use a `radial-gradient` with colour stops with only one element needed. This only works with circles and ellipses, though, and I don't believe you can use boxes with `radial-gradient`s.
2. Adding [`filter: blur(amount)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur) to your CSS will achieve what I think you're looking for - it makes the entire elements blurry so, visually, they will "blend into each other". This method is good as it gives you the best control over everything in terms of position and border radius.

   ```css
   .box3, .box4 {
     filter: blur(20px); /* Makes each box blurry so they blend into each other */
   }

   .box2 {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #333333;
     border-radius: 15px;
     left: 45px;
     top: 30px;
     width: 1750px;
     height: 870px;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #1a1a1a, #333333);
   }

   .box3 {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #4d4d4d;
     border-radius: 15px;
     left: 150px;
     top: 125px;
     width: 1500px;
     height: 700px;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #333333, #4d4d4d);
   }

   .box4 {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #666666;
     border-radius: 15px;
     left: 250px;
     top: 250px;
     width: 1300px;
     height: 450px;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #4d4d4d, #666666);
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="box-container">
     <div class="box1"></div>
     <div class="box2"></div>
     <div class="box3"></div>
     <div class="box4"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Or you can use multiple `inset` [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)s. The benefit of this is you only need one element to achieve what you want, however this might need a little more tweaking to achieve the result exactly. It also won't work with `linear-gradient`s.

   ```css
   .box2 {
     position: absolute;
     background-color: #333333;
     border-radius: 15px;
     left: 45px;
     top: 30px;
     width: 1750px;
     height: 870px;
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #666, #777);
     /* offset-x, offset-y, blur, spread, and the other things */
     box-shadow: 0 0 25px 70px inset #222, 0 0 25px 140px inset #444, 0 0 25px 210px inset #555;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="box-container">
     <div class="box1"></div>
     <div class="box2"></div>
   </div>
   ```

See also: [Square gradient background image, corner radius and transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27501127/square-gradient-background-image-corner-radius-and-transparency)

Comment: Exactly what i needed i ended up using a blur thanks